# kendo ui update grid with dropdownlist

Tags: kendo-ui

I've got a problem with updating kendo ui grid.
I create grid like this one:
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html,
but also I've add update ability.

My problem is in next.

After updating grid, update request goes good (POST url 200 OK), but after it I get an error in browsers console:

```
TypeError: Distribution is undefined.
```

Distribution is type of data in drop down list.

Here is my code:

```
dataSource:
...
update: {    
    url: "/Modeling/EditCurrentStates",
    type: "POST"
}
...
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "StateNumber",
        fields: {
            ...
            Distribution: { defaultValue: { Id: 1, Name: "Exponential"}
            ...

columns: [
    ...
    { 
        field: "Distribution", 
        title: "Distribution", 
        editor: distributionDropDownEditor, 
        template: "#=Distribution.Name#" 
    },

    function distributionDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Id" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind: false,
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    transport: {
                        read: "/Modeling/GetDistributions"
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not define where your datas are coming from to kendo. You need to exe

data: "data"

```
dataSource:
...
update: {    
    url: "/Modeling/EditCurrentStates",
    type: "POST"
}

...
schema: {
    data: "data",
    model: {
        id: "StateNumber",
        fields: {
            ...
            Distribution: { defaultValue: { Id: 1, Name: "Exponential"}
            ...

columns: [
    ...
    { 
        field: "Distribution", 
        title: "Розподіл", 
        editor: distributionDropDownEditor, 
        template: "#=Distribution.Name#" 
    },

function distributionDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Id" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: "/Modeling/GetDistributions"
                }
            }
        });
}
```